# What is the best way to get burdock sticker pieces out of clothing?

Tags: clothing

I went mushroom hunting last weekend, and my flannel shirt got full of burdock sticker pieces. How do I effectively remove all the burdock seed pieces?

Should I wash them with the seed pieces in it to get it out?

Comment: Tweezers -- the burdock has hooks like Velcro (or *vice versa*), and tumbling in a washer or dryer will just tangle more fibers.

Comment: it was a hint of sarcasim

Comment: Didn't mean to be nitpicking. And sorry for the seedy humor.

Comment: Brush them off with a hard brush.

Comment: that ruins the cloths

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use a comb to remove them. I've never tried it though, as I enjoy removing them one by one. If you try it, tell us how it goes.